# Unable to export map in Qgis2leaf

Tags: qgis, qgis2leaf

I am trying to make web map with the help of Qgis2leaf plug in. i added all layer to be plot but when i clicked on OK after setting all parameters i am getting Python coding error. Here i am attaching my error snapshot. Is it related to QGIS version? or related to python plugin for QGIS2Leaf.

[image]

Comment: well, which QGIS version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qgis2leaf is no longer being developed. See the Github repository at https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf. The last commit was on 20 April 2015. Use qgis2web instead, which is under active development - https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web.